# jquery this.bindings[0].val - works but are their ramifications from using this

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jquery:  this.bindings[0].val - works but are their ramifications from using this?  see code example below.  is there a better approach?

```
    $("#editAssignee,#assignee").autocomplete({
        source: GetPersonNamesSource,
        minLength: 4,           
       select: function (event, ui) {
       }

    GetPersonNamesSource = function (request, response) {
        //  var personName = $('#editAssignee').val();
        var personName = this.bindings[0].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: path + '/api/PersonCED/ByBEMSorName/'  + personName,
            data: personName,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 99000,  // 8000= 8seconds, 99000 = 1 Min 39 seconds
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map($.parseJSON(data), function (item) {
                    var LastFirstM = item.LastName + ', ' + item.FirstName + ' ' + item.MiddleName;
                    return {
                        value: item.BEMSID,
                        label: LastFirstM
                        //objPerson: item
                    }
                }))
            } // end success
        }) // end .ajax
    }  // end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to access the value of autocomplete widget inside `source` option callback is via the `term` property of request argument.

For eg:

```
var GetPersonNamesSource = function (request, response) {
  var personName = request.term;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/json',
    data: personName,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 99000, // 8000= 8seconds, 99000 = 1 Min 39 seconds
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map($.parseJSON(data), function (item) {
            var LastFirstM = item.LastName + ', ' + item.FirstName + ' ' + item.MiddleName;
            return {
                value: item.BEMSID,
                label: LastFirstM
                //objPerson: item
            }
        }))
    } // end success
  }) // end .ajax
} // end function
$("#editAssignee").autocomplete({
  source: GetPersonNamesSource,
  minLength: 4,
  select: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

*Side note: The value of `data` option is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. So you might not need to manually append it to the `url`*

Comment: The request.term worked.  I changed the type to a Post and left the data option.